# Android: How to make an adapter with stable ids?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I've made my own custom adapter extended from BaseAdapter to show a listview and so on...

I want it to support single and multi selection, so it must have stable ids. I've checked with the `ADAPTER.hasStableIds()` and the result is false.

I've overrided this method to do try to get stables ids with no luck.

```
public long getItemId(int position) {
   return (long) getItem(position).hashCode();
}
```

Any idea how to make it?
thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Override [hasStableIds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#hasStableIds%28%29) to return true.

Also the data on your adapter must either override `hashCode()` or has some kind of id field to be returned on `getItemId`.

Comment: Wow, simple and easy solution. Thanks!

Comment: hashCodes are not unique and default implementation uses position as id. How hashCode relates to item identifiers?

Comment: @Petr: From what I understood "Stable Ids" means that you are always able to identify your objects/rows using a unique number (aka the Ids never change during the life-cycle of your adapter).
Therefore, in the same way you need unique/not clashing hashCodes for HashMap, you can reuse the hashCode here in your Adapter.

Comment: Hash codes are not guaranteed to be unique. Uniqueness of hash codes within same hash table (e.g. HashMap) is desirable property but not a requirement. I still believe that overriding hashCode() is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: @PetrGladkikh he said: "or has some kind of id field". Though `hashCode` is much weaker than an ID in the data, I agree.

Comment: It's final now. so cannot override it anymore. 
Has to call setHasStablesIds

Answer (score 5):

Add this in your adapter:

```
init {    
    setHasStableIds(true)
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = position.toLong()
```