# Focus lost on refresh in recyclerview

Tags: android

guys I am developing android TV app so I used recyclerview horizontally and vertically and I used a method to refresh adapter of vertical recyclerview by using adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() but I am getting one problem.
1. It's focus is being gone and on press any D-pad key it is not working only right key is working 
2. I used adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, categoryDataList.size()) but I have still one problem that it's focus is going on first element of layout otherwise last of layout.
So Please help me as soon as possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your code for reference

Comment: onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.
.
adapter = new DemoVerticalRecyclerAdapter(this, categoriesVideoList, categoryDataList, mainMenuDataList);
  verticalListView.setAdapter(adapter);
.
.
}

Comment: private void refreshedData() {
  runnable = new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
    Log.e(TAG, "Data refreshed starrt.......");
    // isRefreshedData = true;
    new MyAsycTas().execute();
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    focusedElement();
//    select();
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 9000);
   }
  };

  // handler.postDelayed(runnable,
  // Integer.valueOf(MyStaticClass.refreshTime) * 60000);
  handler.postDelayed(runnable, 9000);
 }

Comment: @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, categoryDataList.size());
   super.onPostExecute(result);
  }

Answer (score 24):

Of course item will lose focus. Because no view to get focus when you refresh RecyclerView by calling method **notify*Changed**.

There is an imperfect way to keep focus in RecyclerView when you call `notifyDatasetChanged()`.

1. Override method getItemId(), give a stable id to each item:
   `@Override public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }`
2. Set has StableId:
   `adapter.setHasStableIds(true);`
3. Now basically you can keep focus in a concrete item when call notifyDatasetChange, if not, disable animator：
   `mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);`

> about stable id:[Android: How to make an adapter with stable ids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267731/android-how-to-make-an-adapter-with-stable-ids)
> about disable animator:[How to implement ItemAnimator of RecyclerView to disable the animation of notifyItemChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873859/how-to-implement-itemanimator-of-recyclerview-to-disable-the-animation-of-notify)
> about the reason of step3 in google code:
> https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=204277

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
notifyItemRangeInserted(position,size);
```

if you are inserting items.

Comment: I have horizontal & vertical recyclerview and getting response from server and we have no idea that item is adding or removing so I am using notifyItemRangeChanged but my focus is going on top